# User AND App readable ID - need to protect dataset

Tags: ios

I am making an IOS app. It will be free in the app store.
Due to Intellectual Property reasons I can not provide the dataset it is working with, so I have the user send me the dataset. I will do some some data processing, which will be my business model.
Then, this dataset has to go back into the app. Since this converted dataset can be easily get into the public domain I want to implement a kind of security mechansism.
Initially I was thinking of having the user enter his Imei/telephone number/Serial number into the website and include it into the converted dataset. The app would verify this data. This way each dataset becomes unique to 1 phone.

However, Apple does not allow anymore to read out any device specific data.
Do you know of an alternative approach?
I am aware of the Vendor ID / Advertisement IDs but these are not user-readable, as far as I know.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Look at the answers that talk about generating a UUID and storing it in the keychain.

Comment: Tnx, but the user can not retrieve that ID from the phone as far as I am aware? So he/she has no means of sending that ID to me so I can encrypt it in the dataset.

Comment: @rmaddy can you please have a look at my reply? Tnx.

Comment: Your app has access to that ID. Simply show it to the user or add a feature to email it to them.

Comment: I should have thought about that myself. ;) Thanks a lot!